# How to save Father and Child document with MongooseJS

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm quite new in MongoDB & MongooseJS. Actually learning the MEAN stack, I already love it.
I'm not sure to exactly understand noSQL principles, sorry If I duplicate.

I want to join 2 documents, type father and child, with 1 to N relationship.

Here's two solutions:
• Sub documents: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html
• References: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

I've chosen the first one, simpler and IHMO closer to my problem.

Here's the code:

```
var personSchema = new Schema({
    name        : String
});

var groupSchema = new Schema({
    name        : String,
    persons     : [ personSchema ]
});


var Group = module.exports = mongoose.model('Group', groupSchema);
var Person = module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

Group.findById(groupId, function(err, group) { 
                        var person = new Person();
                        person.name = "john";
                        group.persons.push(person);

                        group.save();
});
```

When I check for all groups, it work perfectly. The groups are returned, with the people saved.

```
Group.find(function(err, group) { 
    // group is full of groups & people
}
```

But when I check for person, nothing is returned.

```
Person.find(function(err, person) { 
    // person is empty
}
```

It seems that only the Group <s>table</s> document was filled. Is the solution implies to save 1/ the person and 2/ the group, and if so, will Person be saved in two different places (in Group document and in Person document)?

```
Group.findById(groupId, function(err, group) { 
                        var person = new Person();
                        person.name = "john";
                        group.persons.push(person);

                        person.save(function(...) {
                                group.save();
                        });

});
```

Thanks

Comment: >"*The only difference is that* ***they are not saved individually***, *they are saved whenever their top-level parent document is saved.*" says so right in the doc. (Although it could've been clearer and said that "*they are saved* ***with*** *their top-level parent*"). If you want `person` be saved separately you should go for the second approach.

Comment: You face this issue because mongodb doesn't by itself make entries into the child tables. Nor does it join on referred collections to resolve the references. This needs to be handled by the application code. The `group` schema's `persons` field should be of an array of `ObjectId` elements each referring to a record in the `person` schema. In order to make a set of insert, You will need to create `n` persons, store them in the `person` collection. Get their ObjectIds, Create a group with a name and store those ObjectIds in the group's `persons` field as an array of references.

Comment: @laggingreflex, thanks for your comment. If I execute my last code, will my person "john" be saved twice?

Comment: @BatScream thanks. Ok, so you're telling me that the best approach for saving elements in two different tables is the second one (references)

Comment: Yes. the entire person document will be in the 'person' collection and only its objectid in the group collection.